# Why doesn't ubuntu server do an automatic reboot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, reboot, automatic-update

On an Ubuntu 16.04 server I've got AutomaticSecurityUpdates enabled, which works fine. I also want it to automatically reboot at night if needed. For this I've got the following in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`:

```
// Automatically reboot *WITHOUT CONFIRMATION*
//  if the file /var/run/reboot-required is found after the upgrade
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot "true";

// If automatic reboot is enabled and needed, reboot at the specific
// time instead of immediately
//  Default: "now"
Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot-Time "02:00";
```

It has been like this for two days now, but when I ssh into it I still see `*** System restart required ***` and the uptime is more than 7 days.

Does anybody know why this isn't working?

Comment: Was the system upgraded after you changed the config? I guess this check is done right *after* the upgrade (I may be totally wrong though). If so, the message you see may be from before the change.

Comment: Yes, the upgrade was probably from before I set this. But since I've set the reboot time to 02:00 I thought it would simply do a cron to check if the file `/var/run/reboot-required` exists and if so, do a reboot. Or this this work differently?

Comment: Guessing again: it may check just after every upgrade and schedule (or not) one time reboot.

Comment: That could be. Can anybody else confirm that?

Comment: Reboot the server, wait for updates and check whenever it reboots automatically? Go check the update script yourself?